# Ngx-Datatable horizontal scroll permanent enable

Tags: angular, scroll, ngx-datatable

In ngx-datatable, the horizontal scroll bar is hidden when table data is not there and it shows no display data. But the horizontal scroll should show and be able to scroll the hidden column names to the right. How to achieve this?

I tried setting `overflow-x: scroll` in ".ngx-datatable.material.datatable-header" in "style.css" file. It works, but it applies scroll to header even when data is there. ngx-datatable does not support this kinda CR

Comment: it would be helpful if added a minimal code example